# Use of bera writes into margin

Tags: table-of-contents

If I use the bera font in the following example, the table of contents is partially written into the margin. If I remove bera the resulting PDF is fine. What is the best way to solve this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,ngerman,draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bera}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{test}

\newcounter{ctra}
\setcounter{ctra}{1}

\whiledo {\value{ctra} < 100}%
{%
\section{Hallo Welt}\clearpage
\stepcounter {ctra}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: komaissue]

Comment: This is just because the text is now wider than the box that holds the page numbers. Scrbook probably have an interface to change the size of that box. If not look at the tocloft package, which does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say the best approach here would be to use [`tocstyle`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle) (guaranteeing compatibility with KOMA classes) and use an appropriate setting for `pagenumberbox`; for example,

```
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberbox}{\hbox}
```

Your example code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,ngerman,draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberbox}{\hbox}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{test}

\newcounter{ctra}
\setcounter{ctra}{1}

\whiledo {\value{ctra} < 100}%
{%
\section{Hallo Welt}\clearpage
\stepcounter {ctra}%
}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Or, to keep the same alignment as in the original:

```
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{calc}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberbox}{\hspace{0.5em}\parbox{\widthof{999}}}
```

which produces

[image]